# Find the complex (or real) roots of $e^{\frac{3 x}{2}}+2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, roots

Define for natural $n\geq 2$
$$G(x,n)=
\sum _{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k n}}{(k n)!}=
\frac{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} e^{x e^{\frac{2 i \pi  k}{n}}}}{n}=
G(x e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{n}},n)=
\prod_{m=1}^\infty \left(1+\left(\frac{x}{r(n,m)}\right)^n\right)
$$
where $r(n,m)$ is the $m$th biggest absolute value of a root of $G(x,n)$.

The complex roots for $G(x,2)$ and $G(x,4)$ are trivial to find.
$r(2,m)=\left(m-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ and
$r(4,m)=\left(m-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\sqrt{2}$.

Because of rotational symmetry $G(x,3)=G(x e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{3}},3)$, we only need to find the roots on the real line.
Note that
$$G(x,3)=\frac{1}{3} \left(e^x+2 e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)\right)$$
From this we can see that as $x\rightarrow -\infty$, the roots of $G(x,3)$ become arbitrarily close to the roots of $\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$

Because of this, we can use Newton's Method to find the roots of $G(x,3)$ by starting with the roots of $\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$.

The Mathematica code for $r(3,m)$ is

-x /. FindRoot[E^(3 x/2) + 2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] x)/2], {x, -2 Pi (-1/2 + m)/Sqrt[3]}]

This is not good enough though. I desire a formula for $r(3,m)$ which does not not involve a FindRoot. Also, because you could define Newton's method exactly with a limit, limits are not allowed in the final formula.

Because of input from the comments, we now have a new formula for $r(3,m)$:
$$\frac{\pi(2m-1)}{\sqrt{3}}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} (\pi -2 \pi  m)}\right)^n \left(\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi -2 \pi  m}{\sqrt{3}}} \, \frac{\partial ^{n-1}}{\partial x^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x-\frac{\pi -2 \pi  m}{\sqrt{3}}}{-e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} (\pi -2 \pi  m)}+e^{\frac{3 x}{2}}+2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)}\right)^n\right)}{n!}$$
Though Mathematica cannot calculate this, the corresponding Mathematica code is:

-(([Pi] - 2 m [Pi])/Sqrt[3]) - 
 Sum[(-E^(1/2 Sqrt[3] ([Pi] - 2 m [Pi])))^n/n!*
   Assuming[{Element[m, Integers]}, 
    Limit[D[((x - ([Pi] - 2 m [Pi])/Sqrt[3])/(E^(3 x/2) + 
           2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] x)/2] - E^(
           1/2 Sqrt[3] ([Pi] - 2 m [Pi]))))^n, {x, n - 1}], 
     x -> ([Pi] - 2 m [Pi])/Sqrt[3]]], {n, 1, Infinity}]

The remaining work is to find the general $(n-1)$th derivative in the sum and to get rid of the limit in the sum.

Here is a contour plot showing the roots of $G(x,3)$.
The orange curve is $\Im(G(x,3))=0$.
The blue curve is $\Re(G(x,3))=0$.
The plot shows $-10<\Re(x)<10,-10<\Im(x)<10$.
[image: Contour plot]

Also, by comparing the sum and product forms of $G(x,n)$, we can see
$$ \frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r(n,m)^n}$$

Comment: You don't want a FindRoot.  What sort of non-algebraic operations will you permit for this transcendental root?

Comment: @Eric Pretty much anything goes. Could be infinite sums/products, any documented math functions, integrals. What I don't like about FindRoot is that it is an algorithm, rather than a function.

Comment: It's late here, so I'm abandoning my effort.  However, it's worth noting that $3 G(\ln x,3)$ is of the form $x^{u^3} + x^{u^2} + x^{u^1}$ for  $u = \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  (Note that $u^3 = 1$, so the first term is just $x$.)  (Correcting a wildly incorrect characterization from an earlier version of this comment.)

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you for trying. :) Even a formula for r(3,1) would be helpful.

Comment: This boils down to solving $\cos\bigg(\frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg) = -\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{3x}{2}}$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Which boils down to solving $cos(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{x\sqrt 3}$

Comment: @Nazgand WA is telling me that $cos(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{x\sqrt 3}$ has different solutions than you are looking for... how did you get to that conclusion? The equation I give in my comment above still yields the correct solutions.

Comment: When I get to $\log (\cos \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}) = \frac{3x}{2}+i\pi-\log(2)$ WA still can't find a closed form solution, making me wonder if there is one. When I even mess with it a bit I get a closed form in terms of the ProductLog, but the one you gave remains elusive

Comment: I substituted $x\rightarrow \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}$. I should have said $cos(z)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{z\sqrt 3}$ where $z= \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}}$. I was trying to make the problem look simpler. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So... as far as I can tell the problem with finding a closed form here is that we first have to find a closed form for $\log(\cos x) = x  + \pi i \implies \log(|\cos x|) = x \implies \log(\cos^2 x) = 2x \implies \cos^2 x = e^{2x}$

Comment: Oh wow, it is even worse than I imagined... we don't even have a closed form for $\cos x = e^x$. I feel like you'll have to create a new special function to solve this problem

Comment: Infinite sum representations for the roots, expressed in terms of the zeros of the cosine term, aren't too hard to obtain using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) but they aren't pretty.

Comment: @AntonioVargas That seems promising. They both need to be pretty, they just need to be exact and preferably without a limit. Do you think you could make a general formula for r(3,m)?

Comment: But infinite sums definitely involve limits. Numerically it would probably be less efficient than just using Newton's method in the end.

Comment: @EricTowers What do you mean $r(3,m)$ is constant? $r(3,1)\approx 1.84981$ and $r(3,2)\approx 5.44123$

Comment: I'm dubious that you can know the location of these transcendental roots without a limiting process.  To what precision do you *need* to know them.  You have the location of the first root to within 1% (error < $\pi/100$), the second to ~$10^{-4}$, the third to $<10^{-6}$ and so on.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671152/closed-form-for-zeros-of-a-function/4674589#4674589)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute and rearrange:
$$\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt3z}2\right)+\frac12 e^{\frac{3z}2}=0\mathop\iff^{z=\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}}\cos(x)+\frac12 e^{\sqrt3 x}=0\mathop\iff^{x=\ln(w)} w^{2i}+w^{\sqrt3+i}+1=0$$

then substitute $w^{2i}=u\iff w=u^\frac1{2i}e^{\pi k},k\in\Bbb Z$, apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem), and use [factorial power](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower%28a%2Cb%29)

$$w^{2i}+w^{\sqrt3+i}+1=0\iff u=-1-e^{(\sqrt3+i)\pi k}u^{\sqrt[-3]{-1}}\implies x_k=\pi k-\frac i2\ln(u_k)=\pi k-\frac i2\ln(-1)-\frac i2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\big(-e^{(\sqrt3+i)\pi k}\big)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\ln’(t)t^{\sqrt[-3]{-1}n}\right|_{-1}=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi-\frac i2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{\sqrt[6]{-1}(2k+1)\pi n}}{n!}(\sqrt[-3]{-1}n-1)^{(n-1)}$$

Combining this result, the root’s three-fold symmetry, and substituting $k\to-k$ gives:

$$\bbox[2.5px,border: 3px blue solid]{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt3z}2\right)+\frac12 e^{\frac{3z}2}=0\implies z_{m,k}=\frac{(-1)^\frac m3(1-2k)\pi}{\sqrt3}-\frac {i(-1)^\frac m3}{\sqrt3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{\sqrt[6]{-1}(1-2k)\pi n}}{n!}(\sqrt[-3]{-1}n-1)^{(n-1)};k\in\Bbb N,m=0,1,2}$$

where the series [matches](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NumberForm%5B%281-2*%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D%29+%CF%80%2F%E2%88%9A3-i%2F%E2%88%9A3+sum%5Be%5E%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F6%29+%281-2+%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D%29+n+%CF%80%29%2Fn%21+factorialpower%28%28-1%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29n-1%2C+n-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D%2C80%5D) the [actual roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+cos%28%E2%88%9A3+z%2F2%29%2B1%2F2+exp%283z%2F2%29%3D0). If $n=0$, the series diverges so the [Fox Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) cannot easily be used. Also, if all of its parameters were extended to complex numbers and the $n=0$ problem were gone, then Fox Wright would give a closed form.

Answer (score 4):

If we look for the real zeros of function
$$f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}e^{x\sqrt 3}$$ expanding as a Taylor series around $x=-(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$, limited to  $O\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 n+1)\right)^4\right)$and using power series reversion,we have
$$x_n=-(2n+1)\frac \pi 2-$$
$$\frac{99+176 \sqrt{3} (-1)^n T+472 T^2+192 \sqrt{3} (-1)^n T^3+96
   T^4 }{   6 \left(\sqrt 3+2 (-1)^n T\right)^5}$$ where $$T=\exp\left( \frac{(2n+1)\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}   \right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0 &\color{red}{ -1.6019848}34730162686632007 & 
     -1.601984876344266726648546 \\
 1 & \color{red}{-4.712246313369723861}742906 & 
     -4.712246313369723861642345 \\
 2 & \color{red}{-7.853982252057236748320048} & 
     -7.853982252057236748320048 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: What do you think about my answer ? (+1)

Comment: Perhaps you should write $x_n \approx$.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment .

The real zero :

For an iterative method with quick convergence as $\cos(x)<0$ see [Exercise for student about $y\simeq P$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795020/exercise-for-student-about-sqrt-pi-e-2-simeq-wp)

Some details :

Let :

$$\frac{2}{3}x\left(\frac{9}{16}\left(\frac{2}{3}x+1\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{15}{9}+\frac{16}{9}y\right)\frac{9}{16}}{1+\frac{2}{3}x}\right)-y+\frac{x^{4}}{4\left(4x+6\right)}+\frac{x^{5}}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4\left(4x+6\right)}=\frac{x^{5}+5x^{4}+20x^{3}+60x^{2}+120x-120y}{80x+120}$$

Let :

$$f_a(x)=\ln\left(\frac{a}{\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{9}{16}\left(\frac{2}{3}x+1\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{15}{9}+\frac{16}{9}a\right)\frac{9}{16}}{1+\frac{2}{3}x}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x^{3}}{4\left(4x+6\right)}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{x^{4}}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4\left(4x+6\right)}+\frac{x^{5}}{4\cdot5\cdot6\left(4x+6\right)}\right)}\right),a=\left|2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b\right)\right|,h(x)=e^{\frac{3}{2}x}-\left|2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}\right)\right|,g\left(x\right)=f_a\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$$

Then one can show that for example where $a=b_k<0$ is a root for the problem:

Step 1 :

$$h'(y)(b_{k}-y)+h(y)\simeq f_{{b_k}}(y) $$

Then if :

$$h'(y)(b_{k}-y)+h(y)=h(x)$$

Have strictly more than two solution come back to to step 1) with the new value

Step 2)

If it have two solution determine :

$$h'(y)(b_{k}-y)+h(y)=0$$

Come back to step 1)

It gives a new approximated solution

It's like Newton's method .

Comment: Why repost your [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4796259/905886)?

Comment: Because I put and immediately it was deleted it's not fair