# Closed form for zeros of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inverse, transcendental-equations

> I need a closed form for the zeros of $$f(x)=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2} \right)-e^{-\frac{3x}{2}} $$

Putting $x=0$, we see that $f(0)=0$. For the closed form of the remaining zeros we use the series expansion of $f(x)$ about $x=0$ and finally "reversion of series with nth term" ([see here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)) to get a solution $x=x_i$, $i=1,2,3...$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n $$ where $f^{(0)}(0)=f(0)=0$
.
So we have $$f^{(n)}(x)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n\sin\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n e^{-\frac{3x}{2}} $$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-(\sqrt{3})^n\right] \tag{1}$$
Now we discuss two cases:

**Case $1$:** $n$ is even or $n=2m$ where $m\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2m}\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+m\pi\right)-(\sqrt{3})^{2m}\right] $$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2m}\left[\frac{(-1)^m}{2}-(\sqrt{3})^{2m}\right] $$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m}\left[\frac{(-1)^m}{2}-3^{m}\right] \tag{2}$$

**Case $2$:** $n$ is odd or $n=2k+1$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\right)-(\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}\right] $$
Now we have $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(-1)^k$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(-1)^k-(\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}\right] $$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}\left[\frac{(-1)^k}{2}-3^{k}\right] \tag{3}$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(2m)}(0)}{(2m)!}x^{2m}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1} $$
So by $(2)$ and $(3)$
$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{(-1)^m}{2}-3^{m}\right)}{(2m)!}x^{2m}-\frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{2}-3^{k}\right)}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1} $$
**Edit** I tried using  [Langrange inversion theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) but was unable to simply it further.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @TymaGaidash You are right. The reversion formula may be too long. I looked at the links provided by you. Can you please explain how to use Fourier series to find an exact solution. If possible, please write as an answer.

Comment: What makes you think that the "closed form" exists? I doubt that very much. If not a secret, what were you going to do with it anyway?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you for the link. I could not find the solution for the question. I would really appreciate if you could write as an answer. I will with utmost respect accept it.

Comment: @fedja I think that there must be an explicit answer in terms of $x$ in the form of infinite series, even though complicated.

Comment: Or contour integral, or... But suppose you get it. What's next?

Comment: @fedja This is a question by my math Professor. I have to solve it. I request you to write as an answer.

Comment: You mean that's homework? Then I think you've got some hints already ;-) I'll just add that in all likelihood all your Professor is looking for is either a fast way to find the roots (Newton is good) or the first few terms in an asymptotic expansion, but you'd better ask him/her to figure out what is the task exactly. Nothing nice and clean seems to be within reach anyway...

Comment: @fedga Thanks. I would really appreciate for an answer.

Comment: A good approximation to the $n$th positive zero $x_n$ is $$
x_n  \approx \frac{{2\pi }}{{\sqrt 3 }}n + \frac{\pi }{{3\sqrt 3 }} + \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2\sqrt 3 }}\exp \left( { - \sqrt 3 \pi n - \frac{\pi }{{2\sqrt 3 }}} \right).
$$

Comment: @Gary Thanks. Any expression for the nth zero which is not an approximation may be in a form of an infinite series. I would appreciate if you write the expression as an answer and will accept it.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks. I am sorry, I need an almost closed form for my question only. Please see if anything can be done in that direction. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Have a look at my update

Comment: why would you expect the roots to have a closed form?!?!

Comment: @Max The roots likely have a closed form using [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542147/find-the-complex-or-real-roots-of-e-frac3-x22-cos-left-frac-sqrt/4798796#4798796) with [Fox H](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFspWjZm_pk) or [Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Fox%E2%80%93Wright,Maitland%20Wright%20(1935)%3A)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use what @Gary proposed in comments
$$x_n^{(0)}  = \frac{{2\pi }}{{\sqrt 3 }}n + \frac{\pi }{{3\sqrt 3 }} + \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2\sqrt 3 }}\exp \left( { - \sqrt 3 \pi n - \frac{\pi }{{2\sqrt 3 }}} \right)$$ as the starting point of any Newton-like method (Newton, Halley, Householder,$\cdots$) method, the first iterate is fully explicit.

Using (as the simplest) Newton method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_n^{(1)} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & \color{red}{4.2332071}8615947279466285745754 & 
                 4.23320719243895656091540892155 \\
 2 &  \color{red}{7.859792867351540}66752184229490 & 
                  7.85979286735154015594186277305 \\
 3 &  \color{red}{11.4873959924535109930019}408091 & 
                  11.4873959924535109930019824389 \\
 4 &  \color{red}{15.1149947018696098633343674540} & 
                  15.1149947018696098633343674540 \\
 \end{array}
\right)$$ and you can do much better with any method of higher order.

Considering the case of the first root, playing with the order $p$ of the method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \text{estimate for order p} & \text{method} \\
 2 &     \color{red}{ 4.2332071}8615947279466285746 &\text{Newton} \\
 3 &     \color{red}{ 4.2332071}8983134900127366436 &\text{Halley} \\
 4 &     \color{red}{ 4.2332071924389}3072546444189&\text{Householder} \\
 5 &     \color{red}{ 4.23320719243895}485340805279&\text{no name} \\
 6 &      \color{red}{4.233207192438956560}86892954 &\text{no name} \\
 7 &     \color{red}{ 4.233207192438956560914}41334&\text{no name} \\
 8 &     \color{red}{ 4.233207192438956560915408}87 &\text{no name} \\
 \cdots & \cdots &  & \\
\infty &  4.23320719243895656091540892 &\text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

It is possible to make better approximations. Let
$$x=\frac{\pi -6 t}{3 \sqrt{3}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad k=2 e^{\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}}\qquad \implies \qquad k \sin (t)-e^{\sqrt{3} t}=0$$

Expanded around $t=n\pi$
$$ k \sin (t)-e^{\sqrt{3} t}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left( (-1)^n\, k\sin \left(\frac{\pi  m}{2}\right)-3^{m/2}   e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  n}\right) (t-n\pi)^m$$ which allows to perform a complete power series reversion using  Morse and Feshbach general formulation.

This would give for the $n^{\text{th}}$ root
$$t=n\pi+\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m\, Z^m \qquad \text{where} \qquad Z=\frac{e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  n}}{\sqrt{3} e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  n}-(-1)^n\,k}$$

**Update** *(for an example of the reversion)*
As an example, around $t=3\pi$, we have as a series
$$-e^{3 \sqrt{3} \pi }+\left(-k-\sqrt{3} e^{3 \sqrt{3} \pi }\right) (t-3 \pi
   )-\frac{3}{2} e^{3 \sqrt{3} \pi } (t-3 \pi )^2+\frac{1}{6} \left(k-3
   \sqrt{3} e^{3 \sqrt{3} \pi }\right) (t-3 \pi )^3+O\left((t-3 \pi )^4\right)$$
Let $y=(t-3\pi)$ and $a=e^{3 \sqrt{3} \pi }$ to make
$$f(y)=-a-\left(a\sqrt{3}+k\right)y-\frac{3 a }{2}y^2+\frac{k-3
   \sqrt{3} a}{6} y^3+O\left(y^4\right)$$ Now, using the formulae given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)
$$y=-\frac{a+f(y)}{\sqrt{3} a+k}-\frac{3 a (a+f(y))^2}{2 \left(\sqrt{3}
   a+k\right)^3}-\frac{(a+f(y))^3 \left(18 a^2-2 \sqrt{3} a k+k^2\right)}{6
   \left(\sqrt{3} a+k\right)^5}+O\left((f(y)+a)^4\right)$$ Since we want $f(y)=0$, then
$$y=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3} a+k}-\frac{3 a^3}{2 \left(\sqrt{3}
   a+k\right)^3}-\frac{a^3 \left(18 a^2-2 \sqrt{3} a k+k^2\right)}{6
   \left(\sqrt{3} a+k\right)^5}+\cdots$$
To make it looking nicer, let $z=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3} a+k}$
$$y=-z-\frac{3 a }{2 \left(\sqrt{3} a+k\right)}z^2-\frac{\left(18 a^2-2
   \sqrt{3} a k+k^2\right)}{6 \left(\sqrt{3} a+k\right)^2}z^3+O\left(z^4\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your beautiful answer. I would really appreciate if you please provide a form which is exact solution may be in the form of some infinite series.

Comment: @Max. Have a look at paragraph $4.1$ in this paper   http://old.sztaki.hu/~bozoki/oktatas/nemlinearis/SebahGourdon-Newton.pdf  This is what I used for the second part. "Just" make $p\to \infty$.

Comment: +1 for your answer. But my question is to how get an exact solution/ closed form may be in the form of infinite sum or some special function or something else?

Comment: @Max. I wrote the infinite summation

Comment: I am really thankful to you for your recent elegant edit. I have one last question: How did you get the last equality? What is your $a_m$? Can you please explain the intermediate steps involved. I mean how did you get this :$$t=n\pi+\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m\, Z^m \qquad \text{where} \qquad Z=\frac{e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  n}}{\sqrt{3} e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  n}-(-1)^n\,k}$$

Comment: @Max. This is plain power series reversion (have a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html . I hope that you know that what I did with Newton-like method is the same as series reversion. Nice problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks. But sorry I am not able to follow. Please write few steps. I will with utmost respect accept your answer.

Comment: @Max. Make me a favor : expand $ k \sin (t)-e^{\sqrt{3} t}$ around $t=3\pi$ for 3 terms. Compute the inverse series and tell me what you see. I introduced $Z$ in order to simplify.

Comment: The expansion around $t=3\pi$ is $$-e^{3\sqrt{3}\pi}-(k+\sqrt{3})e^{3\sqrt{3}\pi}(t-3\pi) -\frac{3}{2}e^{3\sqrt{3}\pi} (t-3\pi)^2+\frac{1}{6} ( k-3\sqrt{3}e^{3\sqrt{3}\pi}     ) (t-3\pi)^3$$  I have expanded upto 4 terms but just for 3 terms, Sorry I am unable to calculate the inverse.

Comment: @max. I shall edit for this case.

Answer (score 2):

**Set up:** Later on is an explicit Fourier series solution, not needing the [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) formula for:

$$2\sin\left(\frac\pi6-\frac{\sqrt3x}2\right)-e^{-\frac{3x}2}=0$$

Substitute $x\to\frac2{\sqrt 3}x$ and transform the function around the zeros:

$$g(x)=2\sin\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)+e^{-\sqrt3x}=0\implies g_j(x)=(-1)^j(g(x+\pi j)-g(\pi j))=(-1)^j\left(2\sin\left(x+\pi j-\frac\pi6\right)+e^{-\sqrt3(x+\pi j)}-e^{-\sqrt3\pi j}+(-1)^{j+1}\right)$$

The Fourier sine series expands $\sin(3h_j(x))$ on $0\le x<L_j=g_j\left(\frac\pi3\right)=e^{-\sqrt 3\pi j}\left(e^{-\frac\pi{\sqrt3}}-1\right)+2(-1)^j$

where $h_j(x)$ inverts $g_j(x)$. We solve $g_j(x)=(-1)^{j+1}g(\pi j)$ to find the transformed zeros [illustrated here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jwukmspbk8).

**$j=1$: case**

$$g_1(x)=2\sin\left(x-\frac\pi6\right)-e^{-\sqrt3(x+\pi)}+e^{-\sqrt3\pi}+1=e^{-\sqrt3\pi}+1\implies \sin(3 h_1(x))=-\frac2{e^{-\sqrt3\pi}-e^{-\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt3}}+2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L_1}\right)$$

$t\to h_1(t)$ and integration by parts gives:

$$\begin{align}a_n=\int_0^{L_1}\sin(3h_1(t))\sin\left(\frac{\pi n t}{L_1}\right)dt=\int_0^\frac\pi3 \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{L_1}\left(e^{-\sqrt3(t+\pi)}-2\sin\left(t-\frac\pi6\right)-e^{-\sqrt3 \pi}-1\right)\right)\left(2\cos\left(t-\frac\pi6\right)+\sqrt3 e^{-\sqrt3(t+\pi)}\right)\sin(3t)dt\end{align}$$

to get:

$$\begin{align}\sin(3h_1(t))=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac6{\pi n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{e^{-\sqrt3\pi}-e^{-\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt3}}+2}\right)\int_{-\frac\pi 6}^\frac\pi6\sin(3t) \cos\left(\frac{\pi n \left(e^{-\sqrt3\left(t+\frac{7\pi}6\right)}-2\sin(t)-e^{-\sqrt3\pi}-1\right)}{e^{-\sqrt3\pi}-e^{-\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt3}}+2}\right)dt\end{align}$$

$\sin(3 h_1((g_1(x)))=\sin(3x)$ [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bsin%283x%29%2C-sum%5B6%2F%28pi+n%29+sin%28%CF%80+n%2F2.0036+%28-e%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3%28x%2B%CF%80%29%29-2sin%28%CF%80%2F6-x%29%2Be%5E%28-%CF%80%E2%88%9A3%29%2B1%29%29Nintegrate%5Bsin%283+t%29+cos%28pi+n%2F2.0036+%28e%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3%28t%2B7pi%2F6%29%29-2+sin%28t%29-e%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3+pi%29-1%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-pi%2F6%2Cpi%2F6%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%22pi%2F3%22) where $e^{-\sqrt3\pi}-e^{-\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt3}}+2\approx 2.00362$ for $n=10$:

[image]

The series [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F3%28pi-+asin%28-sum%5B6%2F%28pi+n%29+sin%28%CF%80+n%2F2.0036269+%281%2Be%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3+pi%29%29%29+Nintegrate%5Bsin%283+t%29+cos%28pi+n%2F2.0036269+%28e%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3%28t%2B7pi%2F6%29%29-2+sin%28t%29-e%5E%28-%E2%88%9A3+pi%29-1%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-pi%2F6%2Cpi%2F6%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C47%7D%5D%29%29) $h_1\left(1+e^{-\sqrt3\pi}\right)\approx 0.524$ and $x_1=\frac2{\sqrt3}\left(h_1\left(1+e^{-\sqrt3\pi}\right)+\pi\right)\approx 4.233$ [correctly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%2F%E2%88%9A3%280.524625%2Bpi%29).

**General case:**

The roots become ever closer to those of $\sin\left(\frac\pi6-\frac{\sqrt3x}2\right)$, so the setup for $h_j(x)$ is similar like when $j=1$

$$g_j(x)=(-1)^j\left(2\sin\left(x+\pi j-\frac\pi6\right)+e^{-\sqrt3(x+\pi j)}-e^{-\sqrt3\pi j}\right)-1\implies \sin(3h_j(x))=\frac 2{L_j}\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L_j}\right)$$

Using the same techniques:

$$\begin{align}b_n=\int_0^{L_j}\sin(3h_j(t))\sin\left(\frac{\pi n t}{L_j}\right)dt=\int_0^\frac\pi3\sin(3t)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{L_j}g_j(x)\right)dg_j(x)\end{align}$$

and use this branch of the inverse sine for the solution:

$$3 h_j(t)=\pi+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac6\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{e^{-\sqrt 3\pi j}\left(e^{-\frac\pi{\sqrt3}}-1\right)+2(-1)^j}\right)\int_{-\frac\pi 6}^\frac\pi6\sin(3t)\cos\left(\frac{\pi n\left(2\sin(t)+(-1)^je^{-\sqrt3\pi j}\left(e^{-\sqrt3\left(t+\frac\pi6\right)}-1\right)+1\right)}{e^{-\sqrt 3\pi j}\left(e^{-\frac\pi{\sqrt3}}-1\right)+2(-1)^j}\right)\right)dt$$

therefore:

$2\sin\left(\frac\pi6-\frac{\sqrt3x}2\right)-e^{-\frac{3x}2}=0\implies x_j=\frac2{\sqrt 3}(h_j((-1)^{j+1}g(\pi j))+\pi j)$

Setting $j=1$ should match the result in the previous section verifying the above general solution. Fourier series like these [require many terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208845/how-to-compute-dottie-number-accurately) for better accuracy. A simple way to evaluate the coefficients of the form $\int_0^\frac\pi3\sin(3t)\sin(ae^{bt}+c\sin(t)+d)dt$ expands $\sin(y+d)=\sin(y)\cos(d)+\cos(y)\sin(d)$ and then $\cos(y),\sin(y)$ as series. Afterwards, use binomial theorem and integrate, but there may be a simpler result, so the integrals are left alone.

Comment: There is a closed form for $x$ in $\sin(x)-ae^{-\sqrt3x}=0$ with $a$ about between $1$ and $40$. We invert the beta function in [this setup](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+E%5E%285π%2F%282√3%29-+Beta%5B1%2B%282+Cos%5B3+x%5D+-+3+Sqrt%5B3%5D+Cos%5BPi%2F6+%2B+x%5D+%2B+3+Sin%5BPi%2F6+%2B+x%5D%29%2F%283+%28Sqrt%5B3%5D+Cos%5BPi%2F6+%2B+x%5D+-+3+Sin%5BPi%2F6+%2B+x%5D%29%29%2C+2%2F3%2C+1%2F3%5D%29%2Ce%5E%28√3+x%29sin%28x%29) using [inverse beta regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html): $I^{-1}_s\left(\frac23,\frac13\right)$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write a separate answer for the most general case
$$\alpha\,\sin(\beta+\gamma\,x)-e^{\delta\,x}=0\qquad \text{with}\qquad \delta <0$$

Let $$x=\frac{t-\beta }{\gamma }\qquad\qquad a=\frac \delta \gamma\qquad \qquad\epsilon=\frac {e^{-a\beta}} \alpha$$ to write the equation
$$\epsilon  \sin (t)-e^{a t}=0$$ The $n^{\text{th}}$ zero being close to $n\pi$, let
$$t_{(n)}=n\pi +y_n\qquad\qquad b_n=\frac{e^{an\pi}} \epsilon$$ to write the equation
$$(-1)^n\sin(y_n)-b_n\, e^{ay_n}=0$$ From here, I shall use $(b,y)$ in place of $(b_n,y_n)$.

Around $y=0$, the series expansion is
$$(-1)^n\sin(y)-b\, e^{ay}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\, y^k\qquad\text{where}\qquad c_k=\frac{(-1)^n \sin \left(\frac{k\pi  }{2}\right)-b \,a^k}{k!}$$
Then, power series reversion for the result as a infinite summation

$$y=\sum_{m=1}^\infty d_m\,b^m$$
coefficients $d_m$ being computed using Morse and Feshbach formulation.

So, $y_n$ is known and then $t_{(n)}=n\pi =y_n$ and$x_{(n)}$ from its definition.