# Exercise for student about $y\simeq P$

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, continued-fractions, lambert-w, constants

Inspired by [On the cubic counterpart of Ramanujan's $\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}} =1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792229/on-the-cubic-counterpart-of-ramanujans-sqrt-frac-pi-e2-1-frac11-c/4793623#4793623) I made an exercise for the student who are interested by the problem :

Problem :

1).Determine when occurs the relation :$$C+\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=numerator(ax(b_{0}\left(ax+1\right)+b_{1}\cdot\frac{1}{ax+1})$$

Numerator means we take only the numerator without  coefficient in factor which are not coprime .(see the good observation due to Henrik support the community)

2).Using 1). Build a polynomial $f(x)$ which converges to $e^x$

3).Setting $x=0$ after some (numerical works) of iteration with $f_{iteration}(x)$ obtain using a rational approximation of $e^b$ :

$$y\simeq P$$

Where $P$ is a positive rational number .

4).Evaluate the speed of convergence to $y$ .

---

---

I can answer the first question globaly  . I'm really curious for the last question .

1).

$$2/3x(9/16(2/3x+1)+((15)/9+16/9*y)*9/(16)/(1+2/3x))-y=3(1/6x^3+1/2x^2+x-y)/((2x+3))$$

Wich is the case $n=3$

2).$$\frac{2}{3}x\left(\frac{9}{16}\left(\frac{2}{3}x+1\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{15}{9}+\frac{16}{9}y\right)\frac{9}{16}}{1+\frac{2}{3}x}\right)-y+\frac{x^{4}}{4\left(4x+6\right)}$$
Question :

Can you give a clear answer for the exercise ?

Comment: Is the $\text{numerator}$-function you use even well defined? As $1/2=2/4$ I would think that $\text{numerator}(1/2)=\text{numerator}(2/4)$? But perhaps you want to define it as the numerator of the fraction expressed in terms that are relatively prime?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Totally forgot that .Yes for your last question.